# Signing new APK with correct keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, sha1, android-keystore

Briefly: 2 developers working on one Google Play Store independently creating different apps (using Android Studio). Dev 1 signed and created Play Store account some time ago, Dev 2 joined later. Dev 2 created brand new app from scratch, crated new key and was able to upload the first revision to the Play Store.

Now Dev 2 is trying to make changes to his app and upload new revision to Google Play Store, but getting the error that keystores don't match - Play Store is now referring to the first original key created by Dev 1.

What are my options now to upload the new revision of the app to Google Play Store. If possible - step by step please! (click here, type this). Acquiring the key from Dev 1 won't be a problem whatsoever if that makes any difference.

Comment: If it is observed from the the Developer console that the signing key is different from the previous key, & you DON'T have that keystore, there's nothing much you can do except find that keystore.
Alternative is to upload the app as a new one (new package name)

Comment: The thing is that I do have previous key file, but firstly I don't understand how I was able to upload the app with different key, and second of all, I don't know how to replace the keys. My android studio doesn't show 'build new APK' option for some reason

Answer (score 0):

You can contact Google Play Console Support on this issue and they will be able to reset the keystore for you.

In the play console click the help button at the top > Scroll down to heed more help and click "Contact Us" > Type in you need help with a Keystore Reset > Click "next step" > Click "Upload key reset request" > Click "Contact Google Play Developer Support" > Then choose a contact method to contact them to reset it for you.

Comment: Thank you but that will mean any the Dev 1 won't be able to use his key to make updates to his app, is that correct?

I would be happy to use the original, Dev 1 key but at this stage I don't even see 'generate signed bundle/APK' in my 'Build' menu, so I'm totally confused